# what will happen when I use getApkContentsSigners when hasMultipleSigners return false

Tags: android, signature, fingerprint

Our game in production environment uses `getApkContentsSigners` to get apk's signatures regardless of calling `hasMultipleSigners`, and I want to know what will happen in this wrong case.
(So far we haven't found any problems)

```
_______________________
```

in this document [Android SigningInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/SigningInfo#getApkContentsSigners())

It says

"This method(`getApkContentsSigners()`) should not be used unless `hasMultipleSigners()` returns true, indicating that `getSigningCertificateHistory()` cannot be used, otherwise `getSigningCertificateHistory()` should be preferred."

But in my `previous app release`, we use `getApkContentsSigners()` directly with no multiple signers and find no issue so far.

I wonder what exactly happends when I do it in this inappropriate method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in this document [Android SigningInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/SigningInfo#getApkContentsSigners())

It says

 "This method(`getApkContentsSigners()`) should not be used unless `hasMultipleSigners()` returns true, indicating that `getSigningCertificateHistory()` cannot be used, otherwise `getSigningCertificateHistory()` should be preferred."

But in my `previous app release`, we use `getApkContentsSigners()` directly with no multiple signers and find no issue so far.

I wonder what exactly happends when I do it in this inappropriate method.